# Using COUNTIFS to find only unique values

Tags: filter, google-sheets, count, unique, google-sheets-formula

I currently have a table with five columns:

```
A = Campaign
B = Person
C = Opportunity Name
D = Total Cost of Campaign
E = Date
```

I'm trying to use COUNTIFS to count the number of rows that match the exact value in cell H2 to column A and has a date range, in column E, that is greater than the value in cell I2.

I have something like this so far:

```
=countifs($A$2:$A, $H$2, $E$2:$E, ">"&$I$2).
```

However, I'm having a tough time to trying to dedupe this - it should only count unique rows based on the data in column C, where duplicate names exist. Please refer to my data table as reference:

```
Campaign    Person  Opportunity Name    Total Cost of Campaign  Date
A           Bob     Airbnb              5000                   3/2/2017
B           Jim     Sony                10000                  3/2/2017
B           Jane    Coca-Cola           10000                  3/2/2017
C           Jim     Sony                200                    3/2/2017
B           Daniel  Sony                10000                  3/2/2017
B           April   Coca-Cola           10000                  3/5/2017
```

For example:

```
=countifs($A$2:$A, $H$2, $E$2:$E, ">"&$I$2)
```

with `B` in H2 and `3/1/2017` in I2 will give me a result of `4` but I'm really trying to extract a value of `2`, given that there are only two unique names in Column C (`Sony` and `Coca-Cola`).

How could I do this?

Comment: I thought [google-sheets] had a [COUNTUNIQUE](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiC6cjzovzSAhXrhVQKHRu5BmEQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fdocs%2Fanswer%2F3093405%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNH8-WOI3WJXiqVLk06v4JVZ_mICsQ&sig2=I2pEFR6oNA3udEPg2KO6Ag&bvm=bv.151325232,d.cGw) function...?

Comment: Removing the [excel] tag as the solution(s) are **not** cross-platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include column C in your formula and use COUNTUNIQUE function as @Jeeped have suggested. Here is the final formula that you can use:

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(C:C,A:A=H2,E:E>I2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Manish. This works perfectly. Another question - is there an easy way to this to emulate a sumifs for column D?

Comment: Glad to help. And you can add more column (optionally with condition).

Comment: Thank you. Also, in lieu of Sheets lacking a equivalent for SUMIFS (such as  a "sumunique), is there an easy way to do a sum of Column D based on unique values of column C?

Answer (score 2):

Use COUNTUNIQUE with QUERY

```
=countunique(QUERY(A:E,"Select C where A = '"&H2&"' and E > date '" & text(I2,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "'",0))
```

[image]